# Django send email via company's outlook server using smtp

Tags: django, email, outlook

I am trying to send an email via my company's smtp server. Here are my settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'blah'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'blah'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'blah'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Here is the error message I got:

```
[22/Jun/2016 17:31:20] ERROR [uer_application.views:68] Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cheng/Dev/diandi/uer_application/views.py", line 65, in send_email
  File "/Users/cheng/Dev/diandi/uer_application/views.py", line 65, in send_email
    email.send(fail_silently=False)
    email.send(fail_silently=False)
  File "/Users/cheng/.virtualenvs/diandi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
  File "/Users/cheng/.virtualenvs/diandi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/cheng/.virtualenvs/diandi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
  File "/Users/cheng/.virtualenvs/diandi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/cheng/.virtualenvs/diandi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
  File "/Users/cheng/.virtualenvs/diandi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')
```

I tested the username and password via the web portal and it works. So I am curious if there is anything wrong in my settings file (or maybe I missed something?)

### Update

Thanks guys, a STUPID mistake that I made:

Username should be without the `@blah.com` part...

Comment: Are you sure about the port? While 587 is the default smtps port, some servers listen on 25 for smtps. That fixed the problem for me some weeks ago.

Comment: For me port 25 worked

Comment: @Cheng, hey, have you found a solution for this, please?

Comment: @MurphyAdam See the update a the bottom of the post

Comment: @Cheng, Thank you, but no lack. Still same error. My username goes like info@example.com, removing all, only 'info' is left. Do you mind please if you shared with me an example settings, including EMAIL_HOST?

Comment: @MurphyAdam sorry, I haven't touched this code for years (the timestamp is 2016...) I wouldn't be able to recall the details

Answer (score -1):

Use this,

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'Your gmail address'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Your password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Make sure you are providing a vaild gmail id and its password

Comment: The question says "via my company's smtp server", so using Gmail is not an option.